# Simplifying a fraction with sums of polynomials in the numerator

Tags: polynomials, maxima, fractions, simplification, wxmaxima

I'm trying to simplifying the following in maxima:

```
(6*C*b3m*ω+(8*%i*R0^3*b^3-24*%i*R0^3*a*b^2+24*%i*R0^3*a^2*b-8*%i*R0^3*a^3)*Γ+3*A*E*a3p*k+2*%i*K*b3m)/(6*C*ω+3*A*E*k+2*%i*K)
```

So far, here's what I get :
[image: wxmaxima output]

But I can easily see that the quantity in brackets there is nothing but `(8*R0**3*(b-a)**3)*Γ`. In fact I can see this by just evaluating this :

[image: evaluation of simplification]

It's frustrating to see maxima miss this and I don't know what to do to simplify this. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: My only workaround so far is to use `subst([bma=b-a], factor(RT1Lh3(a,a+bma)));` (where RT1Lh3(a,b) is a function returning the above expression). This is ugly and I don't like it.

Comment: Try applying `num` to get the numerator of the ratio and then `ratcoeff(something, Γ)` to get the expression you showed, and then apply `factor` to that. There are some expression-transforming functions which I don't know very well -- `facsum`, `factorfacsum`, `collectterms`, etc. You might try bringing up the topic on the maxima-discuss mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent this through the maxima mailing list and got a response from Barton Willis (willisb@unk.edu). I'm posting the answer here so it will be useful for others:

> Try using scanmap('factor,%); thus:
>
> (%i10)
> (6*C*b3m*ω+(8*%i*R0^3*b^3-24*%i*R0^3*a*b^2+24*%i*R0^3*a^2*b-8*%i*R0^3*a^3)*Γ+3*A*E*a3p*k+2*%i*K*b3m)/(6*C*ω+3*A*E*k+2*%i*K)$
>
> (%i11)   scanmap('factor,%);
>
> (%o11)
> (6*C*b3m*ω+8*%i*R0^3*(b-a)^3*Γ+3*A*E*a3p*k+2*%i*K*b3m)/(6*C*ω+3*A*E*k+2*%i*K)
>
> --Barton

Here's the expression in wxmaxima:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If ex is your original expression, try substpart(factor(piece),ex,1,1).

Comment: This works, with the slight modification that you had suggested over email: `substpart(factor(piece),ex,1,2)`

Answer (score 1):

ratsubst(bma,b-a,your_expression)
shows most of the structure you seem to wish to see.

If you have questions about maxima specifically, posting on the maxima mailing list may get a faster response. Make sure your post includes enough detail (version, exact transcript) so that anyone can reproduce your interaction.  Have fun!